# htaccess mod_rewrite to example.com/tut/2

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to convert the link in my website to this way :

```
wwww.example.com/tut/1
```

from

```
wwww.example.com/tut.php?v=1
```

I tried alot of way but no thing happen

my code was this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tut/(\d+) tut.php?v=$1 [QSA,L]
```

is there is any other idea or code ??

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code in root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /tut\.php\?v=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /tut/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^tut/(\d+)/?$ tut.php?v=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: what do you mean root htaccess?

Comment: i.e. `.htaccess` in your `DocumentRoot` folder.

Comment: What URL did you enter in browser and where is this .htaccess located? Are you sure .htaccess is working?

Comment: yes i'm sure because i tried with other code to remove .php and it's work 
badrsh.me/tut.php?v=1
this is the website
and this is my test to remove .php badrsh.me/tut

Comment: Then I think your rules are conflicting as `badrsh.me/tut/1` is trying to load `badrsh.me/tut/1.php` Place these rules before other rules OR place your current htaccess in question so that I can suggest better.

Comment: no when i tried your code i removed the last one and  there was no other your code 
and i  put it again to show you the other htaccess is worked

Comment: As I suggested place your current .htaccess in question. `http://badrsh.me/tut/1` is now giving 404 so even 2nd rule is not functioning which is working fine on my Apache. Retest after commenting `RewriteBase` line also